# Разбор предложения

Tags: сказуемое

В каком предл-и сказуемое выражено неопределенной формой глагола?
Туман начинает понемногу рассеиваться.
Вам не видать таких сражений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Естественно, "не видать". А в чем Ваше затруднение?

Comment: Я и сама так думала, что правильный ответ есть *не видать*, просто меня запутало то, что и в первом предложении есть инфинитив - *рассеиваться*, и это слово входит в состав сказуемого. А теперь уточнила, спасибо, что помогли.

Answer (score 0):

В предложении "Вам не видать таких сражений" нет сказуемого, а есть главный член предложения, выраженный инфинитивом с отрицанием". 
 составное глагольное сказуемое ***"начинает рассеиваться" (второе слово - инфинитив);***